# Playdate in Italian

Tags: word-choice, idioms, single-words

When parents arrange a time for their children to meet and play, in English that is called a *"playdate"* or *"play date"*. Is there an equivalent *lemma* or *locuzione* in Italian?

I would find natural to say *"appuntamento per giocare"* or *"appuntamento per far giocare i bambini"* which do not sound very fresh though, to me they sound slow and tedious.

Any hint?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The basic fact is that there is not even an exact correspondence between the English word “date” (in the present meaning) and any Italian word. One of the nearest is *appuntamento*, but you can have an *appuntamento* with a friend, with the dentist, and so on, while talking about a date involves explicitly a romantic interest, to the point that a couple might try to ascertain whether a meeting they had was, or not, a date.
In Italian you have to use a periphrasis, perhaps involving *vedersi* or *uscire insieme* (or something completely different to the same effect). There is no one-to-one correspondence between the words of different languages.
So, for our “playdate”, depending on the context it appears in, I would probably express it with a phrase with a completely different structure, about, say, «*portarli a giocare con gli amichetti*», «*far venire gli amichetti a casa*» or, often, something involving a *merenda* or whatever.

Comment: perfect answer (except maybe for the word "question", which I think is an Italianism...)